# Problem with copying data from an image to WPF IMage

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm TRYING to create an application which utilizes drag and drop functionality.

I've been on this everyday for the past week and I can't get a clear answer I can understand.

What I basically want to do, is to take an image from file explorer and copy its data into WPF Image control.

I have done few mothods listed here, but nothing seems to work.

I'm not sure if it's impossible or I'm doing something wrong.

I CAN get the data from the image, but I CAN'T convert it to a format that the Image control can use.

```
private void TestDrop_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            byte[] files = (byte[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);


        }

    }
```

I've been using the code that's been usually suggested on similiar topics, however I just can't transfer said data to the Image control and I can't even convert it to the right type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop a set of files, `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)` returns an array of file paths:

```
private void TestDrop_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) &&
        e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) is string[] files &&
        files.Length > 0)
    {
        // load first image file
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[0]));
    }
}
```